# DateDiff() Hours and Minutes?

Tags: sql-server, datediff

This question have been asked many times but i cannot find any easy answers on how to get hours and minutes from a `datediff()`.

```
From    To  OUTPUT
08:00   16:30   8,5
10:00   16:30   6,5
08:00   15:00   7
```

I would like to use `datediff()` and want the output as my result

Comment: How is your data stored?

Comment: i want datediff(hours&minutes,from,to) as OUTPUT

Comment: How are from and to stored?

Comment: The datepart passed to DATEDIFF will control the resolution of the output. example, if start_date and end_date differed by 59 seconds, then DATEDIFF(MINUTE, start_date, end_date) / 60.0 would return 0, but DATEDIFF(second, start_date, end_date) / 3600.0 .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went with

```
DATEDIFF(second, start_date, end_date) / 3600.0
```

Thank you all for the answers...!!.

Comment: when I try this I get 
```Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'DATEDIFF'```

Answer (score 3):

Sorry, I answered C# question first :)

What you're after is this:

```
SELECT datediff(minute, starttime, endtime) from ...
```

of course, you can apply this to hours too. 
For Hours AND minutes, you can use this example:

```
DECLARE @start datetime
      , @end   datetime

SELECT @start = '2009-01-01'
     , @end   = DateAdd(mi, 52, DateAdd(hh, 18, DateAdd(dd, 2, @start)))

SELECT @start
 , @end

SELECT DateDiff(dd, @start, @end)      As days
     , DateDiff(hh, @start, @end) % 24 As hours
     , DateDiff(mi, @start, @end) % 60 As mins
```

Comment: Hi, i do not want them as 2 or 3 different columns. can you provide the output column for me?

Comment: Just replace comma with + ' '

Comment: that will result in arimatic addition. you need to convert to string first before using +

Answer (score 2):

just take datediff() by minute and then divide by 60

```
select  datediff(minute, '08:00', '16:30') / 60.0
```