# DATEDIFF in Hour:MIN format for DATETIME in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I have a requirement to get time difference between two DateTime's in HH:MM format not decimal.

Eg:

```
DECLARE @D1 DATETIME = '2019-11-18 06:00:00', @D2 DATETIME = '2019-11-19 10:23:00'
```

I need Time Diff as 28:23 not with decimals. I found related article [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35840300/datediff-hours-and-minutes) but not forDATETIME format. Any suggestion

Comment: I'm having format deviation compared to provided/suggested URL's. Why is my query closed with related info but not exact answer

Answer (score -1):

you can try like below

```
DECLARE @D1 DATETIME = '2019-11-18 06:00:00', 
@D2 DATETIME = '2019-11-19 10:23:00' 
select convert(varchar(5),DateDiff(s, @D1, @D2)/3600)+':'+convert(varchar(5),DateDiff(s, @D1, @D2)%3600/60)
```

output

```
col
28:23
```

Comment: I'm getting -ve value for duration at this example. Please check

`DECLARE @D1 DATETIME = '2019-11-18 11:22:45.277', @D2 DATETIME = '2019-11-18 12:09:35.103'
select concat( datediff(hour,@D1,@D2),':', cast( round( (cast(datediff(second,@D1,@D2)/3600.00 as decimal(10,5))-cast ( datediff(hour,@D1,@D2) as int))*60,1) as int))`

Comment: This should work

`DECLARE @D1 DATETIME = '2019-11-18 11:22:45.277', @D2 DATETIME = '2019-11-18 12:09:35.103'
select convert(varchar(5),DateDiff(s, @D1, @D2)/3600)+':'+convert(varchar(5),DateDiff(s, @D1, @D2)%3600/60)`

Comment: @Shalem thanks i have added your comments as a answer

Comment: @Shalem - That work's for me. Thanks